# Add factor column to dataframe based on existing column

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
word <- c("good", "great", "bad", "poor", "eh")
userid <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
d <- data.frame(userid, word)
```

I want to add a dataframe column, `sentiment`, that is a `factor` and depends on what `word` is:

```
words_pos <- c("good", "great")
words_neg <- c("bad", "poor")
calculate_sentiment <- function(x) {
     if (x %in% words_pos) {
         return("pos")
     } else if (x %in% words_neg) {
         return("neg")
     }
     return(NA)
}
d$sentiment <- apply(d, 1, function(x) calculate_sentiment(x['word'])
```

However, now `d$sentiment` is of type "character". How do I make it a factor with the right levels? `pos`, `neg`, `NA` -- I'm not even sure if `NA` should be a factor level, as I'm just learning R.

Thanks!

Comment: Try: d$sentiment<-factor(d$sentiment)

Comment: Don't you apply if only need it for a single column. This is both dangerous (because matrix conversions) and very inefficient. And I think you are looking for `addNA` instead of `factor`. Something like `addNA(sapply(word, calculate_sentiment))`. Not to mention that you probably could easily vectorize this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't going to be the simplest way to do it, but it's a very readable  way (in my opinion, preferable to using an abstracted function)... using `dplyr`'s `mutate` along with `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
d2 <- mutate(d, sentiment = factor(case_when(word %in% words_pos ~ "pos",
                                             word %in% words_neg ~ "neg",
                                             TRUE                ~ NA_character_)))

glimpse(d2)
#> Observations: 5
#> Variables: 3
#> $ userid    <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
#> $ word      <fctr> good, great, bad, poor, eh
#> $ sentiment <fctr> pos, pos, neg, neg, NA
```

I've spaced it out a bit so it's clearer, but this will:

- take the `data.frame` `d` then
- `mutate` (change a column) 'sentiment' to be equal to a factor, defined by
- a `case` statement with logicals on the LHS, results on the RHS (`NA_character_` required so that everything is the same type).

Output confirms that this is a `factor` column with the desired values.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `as.factor` to the last line of the code. Which will give factors of pos and neg. BTW NA is not a factor.

`d$sentiment <-as.factor(apply(d, 1, function(x) calculate_sentiment(x['word'])))`